# Hadoop - search particular strings then returned filename that containt the strings

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

In hadoop hdfs, how to write a command that list down all the files that contain string 'SFD'

To search string, here the command, and I can get the results, but I want to know which files contain this string 'SFD' and I've thousand files in test directory.

```
hadoop fs -cat /test/*.txt | grep SFD
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
hadoop fs -ls /test/*.txt | awk '{print $8}' | while read f; do hadoop fs -cat $f | grep SFD && echo $f ; done
```